# How to parse the dom in Nuxt on server-side?

Tags: nuxtjs3

I have an HTML structure I inject in Nuxt, and I need to parse it to extract some data.

Using client-side is easy by calling DOM functions in javascript (querySelectorAll, .classlist, .id, etc).

Is it possible to do something similar, but on the server-side, something like

```
const fakeDom = virtualDom(myHtmlVariable)
const mainId = fakeDom.querySelector('h1').id
```

The closest I was able to do is add a `ref` to my HTML element (`<div ref="domContent" v-html="htmlContent"></div>`) and then `watch` the value change, to handle the DOM, but it results in some delay before being processed.

Another approach would be to use regex to parse the HTML on the server-side, but I don't want to go that road.